# How to get an HTML element to always display 0 as a number when using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I've started coding roughly a month ago, so thanks for your understanding if this could've been explained better.

I am trying to have a span always display 0 when clicking a button that decreases the original amount. Instead of that happening, I am continuously getting negative numbers.

`<span class="badge" id="num">40</span>` to be `<span class="badge" id="num">0</span>` after clicking the button with this function

```
function connectionRequestCount(num) {
  document.querySelector(num).innerText--
}
```

instead, it continues with negative numbers when clicking the button `<span class="badge" id="num">-5</span>` and so on.

I've also tried getElementById & ClassName.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: you mean you want it to stop at zero without going negative?

Comment: correct. For some reason it continues past 0. Would it be some type of for loop?

Comment: so to be clear - it says `0`, you press the button, and then it goes `-1`, but you want it to stay at `0`?

Comment: it starts out at ```40``` connection requests. When either accepting or rejecting said connection request, bringing that span to ```0``` , yes, it continues past to ```-1``` etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent the number from decreasing when it is zero, just check within the function:

```js
function connectionRequestCount(num) {
  +document.querySelector(num).innerText && document.querySelector(num).innerText--
}
```

This makes sure that `num`'s text isn't `0` before decrementing it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the swift response. I really appreciate it! Out of curiosity, what does the + do in front of .document?

Comment: @CoyoteCoder it's a unary operator to convert to a number -- necessary because while `0` is falsy, `"0"` is truthy -- we want to go from `"0"` to `0` when it is zero

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```js
function connectionRequestCount(num) {
  if(document.querySelector(num).innerText!=0){
    document.querySelector(num).innerText--;
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="badge" id="num">40</span>
<button onclick="connectionRequestCount('#num')">Click Me!</button>
```

So when ever the button is clicked at 0, because of the if statement it will not go inside and not decrement the value then.

Hope that helps you
Thank You!

Comment: Hey Ayush, thanks so much for the assist! Essentially, if I am reading your code correct, with ```if(document.querySelector(num).innerText!=0)``` We're saying if the number is not zero, decrement, but if it is, do not change this.

Comment: Yes @CoyoteCoder, if the number is not 0, the code inside the if statement executes but if not, it does not enter the if statement and nothing happens